# Install VirtualBox on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I downloaded virtualbox from [Here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).
And i tried to install it by running the following command

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.20-96996~Ubuntu~raring_i386.deb
```

And error occured in installation as :

```
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-4.3.
(Reading database ... 345499 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-4.3_4.3.20-96996~Ubuntu~raring_i386.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-4.3 (4.3.20-96996~Ubuntu~raring) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-4.3:
 virtualbox-4.3 depends on psmisc.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-4.3 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-4.3
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Can't you install it with apt-get from the official repositories?

Comment: or you can do is `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` since virtualbox is in ubuntu repositories by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dpkg does not manage dependencies.

So now

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then install again

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.20-96996~Ubuntu~raring_i386.deb
```

Otherwise, I completely agree with the suggestion to use KVM (virt-manager) rather then virtualbox and if you must use virtualbox, install it from the repositories.

See: http://virt-manager.org/

The advantage of virt-manager is that it is open source and in does not require 3rd party code. Although virtualbox is in the repositories, not all the features available for virtualbox are open source.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise that unless there is some particular reason you use that particular type of virtual machine manager, that you instead open the "Ubuntu Software Center" and select its own "Virtual Machine Manager" which automatically accommodates all of the dependencies without any necessity for pre-installing anything or, asking advice of others on this site, for that matter.

At least, it seems worth a shot.  Installing "Virtual Machine Manager" is exactly what I did almost a year ago and I haven't stopped bragging about the results yet.  I carry with me an external USB drive to which I am running virtual machine under Ubuntu with five separate and differently configured windows installations, and I don't describe myself as remotely expert in this area.

Please just try doing it the EASY WAY first, and only resume the hard way if or when you discover an unacceptable limitation.

Comment: FWIW, it is called virt-manager

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in logs:

> virtualbox-4.3 depends on psmisc.

You have missing `psmisc` package, just install it, something like follows:

```
sudo apt-get install psmisc
```

Comment: That command, as written, will not work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing from repository by:

```
 sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```